# What's the difference between Final Cut Pro X and Final Cut Studio?

Tags: final-cut-pro

I visited the Wikipedia page about Final Cut Studio, which is apparently aimed at professional movie studios. The page says that it's now only available via a 1-800 number, but the link to the official page for Studio at Apple now points at Final Cut Pro X. Also, the prices are wildly different. $299 for Pro X. Around $800 for Studio according to some results on Google.

Is Studio an old, retired product and the high end editor suite is now Pro X (with an apparent huge slash in price), or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Final Cut Pro X is the new high-end professional video editor. When it was released, the pro video editors revolted, as they rewrote Final Cut Pro, changed the interface, and took out a lot of features they relied on. So, if you're a pro and you want to spend a lot of money on the old version, you call Apple and make an arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Final Cut Studio is the discontinued version of what is now Final Cut Pro X, the newer version of Apple's pro video editor. Final Cut Studio had some features and structure that Final Cut Pro X doesn't have, which is why it's more expensive, as it is now more specialized.

I would like to point out that you can find Final Cut Studio 3 on sites like eBay for significantly less than $800. I've found some full installation disk sets for about $90, making it cheaper than Final Cut Pro X. I would check eBay and other sites as it's cheap enough that you buy both and if you don't like one of them, you have the other, or if one doesn't have a feature, the other may have the feature you need.